# Lift (Scala) Custom Form with Snippet

Tags: scala, authentication, lift

Hello fellow programmers,
as you might know from my previous questions I'm an absolute newbie in the Scala/Lift world, therefore I might ask some trivial questions, sorry for that :)

I'd love to make a custom login form to authenticate a user (the user is not authenticated via a database but instead via an API call through Google Protocol Buffer), so all I need to do is grab the inputs and send them to the API.

So far, I came up with my `login.html` page:

```
<div id="loginContainer" class="loginMainContainer centerContainer">
      <div class="loginInputWrapper">
        <input type="text" name="loginName" id="loginName" class="txtLogin" />
      </div>
      <div class="loginInputWrapper">
        <input type="password" name="loginPassword" id="loginPassword" class="pwLogin" />
      </div>
      <div class="buttonWrapper loginButtonWrapper">
        <button type="submit" class="hiddenButton qsbfont">Login</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and I want to grap the `loginName` and `loginPassword` field values. Which is the (best) way to achieve this?

I tried to get it with this class and add it to the `snippet` package, but I can't figure out how to wire these two together. Here's my snippet:

```
object MyAuthentication {
  def authentication(name: String, password: String) = {

    def validate(user: String, password: String): Boolean = {
      if(user == "tac" && password == "tac") true else false
    }

    def createUser(loggedIn: Boolean): Boolean = {
      if (loggedIn) {
        val user = new MyUser
        user.setName(name)
        user.setUID(1111)
        user.setLoginState(loggedIn)
        user.setLanguage("en_EN")
      }
      loggedIn
    }

    if (createUser(validate(name, password)))
      <span>loggedIn</span>
    else
      <span>failure!</span>

  }

  def render = SHtml.onSubmitList(credentials => {
    authentication(credentials(0), credentials(1))
  })

}
```

So, is it possible like that? How can I wire these two things together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but hopefully a pointer for where to start:

Check out [this Ajax Form demo](http://demo.liftweb.net/ajax-form). The related scala source is [here](https://github.com/lift/examples/blob/master/combo/example/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/example/snippet/AjaxForm.scala) and the template source is [here](https://github.com/lift/examples/blob/master/combo/example/src/main/webapp/ajax-form.html).

This seems to be similar to what you're trying to do. The way they tie everything up is to wrap the fields of what-would-be-the-form in a `<lift:snippet type="AjaxForm:show" form="post">`. Then on the server side, the `show` method takes the template xml (they use `Group` as the argument type, but I'm pretty sure you can interchange that for `NodeSeq`) and bind the fields to Ajax-enabled fields.

Note the `import SHtml._` in the demo's source... frankly I dislike the demos for doing this as it makes it hard to understand where methods are coming from, for newcomers to Lift. Methods like `untrustedSelect`, `select`, `submit`, and `ajaxCall` are coming from that import.

As a last note, I find [Lift's Google Groups page](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/liftweb) to be more helpful than SO for Lift-related questions. I'm no Lift guru, but the people there are. Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot - I'll give a try and repost here what's my result ;)

Answer (score 0):

this is a lik to a page on how to make a form http://simply.liftweb.net/index-4.1.html#toc-Section-4.1

point to note though there should be no div tags inside a `<div class="lift:LoginForm">code goes here</div>` I prefer this because it allows more control.